# Create multidimensional array from database query

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, hierarchy

I have a database that stores accounts and subscriptions. An account can contain accounts and subscriptions and have more than three parent levels.

A row from the database query result looks something like this:

```
$array = (0 => array("level" => "2", "accountno" => "123124234", "accountname" => "Hansel", "parentaccountno" => "000213123", "subscription" => "5423213213", "username" => "Gretchen");
```

(Level 1 means that it is top level and it will have PARENTACCOUNTNO = null).

From this I am trying to create a multidimensional array which looks something like this:

```
accounts:
    000213123
        accounts:
            123124234
                name: Hansel
                subscriptions:
                    5423213213
                        username: Gretchen
```

This is the code I have so far, which works really well on the first two levels. When there are are three levels or more things become more complicated, since each account only knows about its own parent:

```
$hierarchy = array();

foreach ($decode as $row) {
    $accountno = $row["ACCOUNTNO"];
    $msisdn = $row["MSISDN"];
    if ($row["PARENTACCOUNTNO"] == null)
        $base_array_key = $hierarchy["accounts"];

    $base_array_key[$accountno] = array("name" => $row["ACCOUNTNAME"], "accounts" => array(), "subscriptions" => array());

    $hierarchy["accounts"][$accountno]["accounts"]["321323123213"] = "blaha";

    if ($row["MSISDN"] != null)
        $hierarchy["accounts"][$accountno]["subscriptions"][$msisdn] = array("enduser" => $row["ENDUSER"]);
}
```

The solution I have in mind right now is to pass the base key from each iteration to the next iteration, and then if for example the previous level was two levels above this one just use some sort of string replace to remove the last two parts of the key.

Any better ideas? I am quite sure this is a shitty way of doing what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is this a `complete my code` question? or you got error somewhere?

Comment: No error, just looking for some friendly advice on something I have been stuck on for about a week trying to find the *optimal* solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the answers, but I think the problem is my database query which should contain records of all the parents of an account and not just the parent, using something like SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary associative array:

```
$all_records = array();
```

Populate it with the results you find in the database:

```
while($result = get_results_from_db()) {
    $accountno = $result[accountno];
    $all_records[$accountno] = $result;
}
```

Now you have an array indexed by account numbers so it's easy to find any record if you know it's account number. So you iterate through the array to associate children to parents:

```
$top_level_records = array();
foreach($all_records AS $record) {
    $parentaccountno = $record[parentaccountno];
    if(!empty($parentaccountno)) {
        $parent = &$all_records[$record[parentaccountno]];
        if(empty($parent['accounts']))
            $parent['accounts'] = array() 
        $parent['accounts'][] = $record;
    }
    else {
        $top_level_records[] = $record;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all your results look like that ? So then, where's are the parent accounts ? Or am i missing something ? I would simple rewrite the query to get a more "linear" result, like:

```
parentaccountno | accountno | accountname | bla
-----------------------------------------------
000213123       | 123124234 | Hansel      | abc
```

When every result row looks like this, you can simple create your final array like that:

```
foreach ($decode as $row) {
    $my_array = [ $row["parentaccountno"] ][ $row["accountno"] ]["accountname"] = $row["accountname"];      
    $my_array = [ $row["parentaccountno"] ][ $row["accountno"] ]["bla"] = $row["bla"];     
}
```

Comment: Each row is an account and a subscription, with an optional reference to a parent account. That means that any row could be a parent account, or a parent to a parent account, or a parent to a parent to a parent account, etc.